Future movie with androids with guns on their arms?
I saw a movie in the late 90's on tv and have been trying to figure out what the name of it was. I believe it was an 80's movie and took place in the future. There was a group of soldiers with a mission to escort a scientist to some destination. I remember there were androids or robots with guns on their arms that the human soldiers had to fight. There was also some sort of virus that would make the humans disappear. I remember at the end the scientist was able to go back in time and meet himself so the whole apocalyptic future wouldn't occur.

Possibly A.P.E.X. from 1994. From Wiki:

In the year 2073 Nicholas Sinclair is a scientist on a time travel project. An accident introduces a deadly virus in to the past in 1973, causing a paradox. The project's automatic countermeasures activate and attack robots are sent in to the past to try to eliminate the virus carriers. They fail to contain the virus, and Sinclair returns to 2073 to find the Earth in ruins, ravaged by both the virus and the attack robots continually sent from the original timeline.

The robots looked like this:

